# Simple solution to the following system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Is there an easy way to find that $F = I$ in the following system of equations?

$$ c^2I^2-F^2v^2=c^2$$
$$ F^2-c^2J^2=1 $$
$$ c^2IJ+F^2v = 0$$ 
$$ c > 0 $$

Comment: This is false. Take $c=\nu=0$. Then $F^2=1$ and $I$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: this is not a convincing argument. Because $c$ and $v$ are not necessarily equal.

Comment: But they could be equal. And then there is no easy way to find that $F=I$. I assume that all variables are real numbers?

Comment: how could you know that there is no easy way to solve that System?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: it depend if the question is $\exists c,v,J$ such that $F=I$, or $\forall c,v,J$: $F=I$, or something different.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, this makes sense. I was thinking, the question asks that the given system in the variables always implies that $F=I$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: with no restriction on the variables, you are right, $F\ne I$ in general.

Comment: Well i think there is a problem some were then because this system of equations is what i got from trying to solve Lorentz transformation as is done in W. Rindler, Introduction to relativity, where c is the speed of light, and therefore is positive, and he says that $ F=I $ for any values of $ v$ and $c>v $, now that i think about it i should have put those two expressions in the system of equations, but when trying to solve them by Wolfram Alpha i did not put those and he did gave me that $I=F$ or $N=-I$ and $c\neq0$ .

Answer (score 0):

Assume $F=I$. The system reads

$$ c^2I^2-I^2v^2=c^2,\\ I^2-c^2J^2=1,\\ c^2IJ+I^2v = 0.$$

Then from the second equation

$$J^2=\frac{I^2-1}{c^2}$$ and from the third (after squaring) $$c^4I^2\frac{I^2-1}{c^2}=I^4v^2,\\c^2(I^2-1)=I^2v^2,$$

which is compatible with the first equation.

But this works only if

$$I^2=\frac{c^2}{c^2-v^2}.$$

Comment: And we have to assume that $c\neq 0$, $c^2\neq v^2$.